# Bresenham for spheres?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, graphics, 3d

I am writing simple a software renderer, and it 
works quite good, (working with triangle and sphere/circle
primitives) but I've got some problems with depth buffer 
implementation - I need a version of Bresenham's circle
algorithm that would be working with correct 3d values
(needed to fill depth buffer). Simple 'flat' 2d circle version.

```
    void FillCircleWithDepth(int x1, int y1, float z, int radius, unsigned color)
    {


     int left   = x1-radius-1;
     int right  = x1+radius+1;
     int up     = y1-radius-1;
     int down   = y1+radius+1;


     if(!_rectanglesOverlap(0, 0, CLIENT_X, CLIENT_Y,
                    left, up, right, down ) )
         return;


     int x  = 0;                   //0
     int y  = radius;              //1
     int d1 = 3 - (2 * radius);

     do
    {
     if (d1 < 0)      d1 += (x<<2) + 6;
     else             d1 += ((x-(y--))<<2) + 10;

     drawScanlineWithDepth(y1+x, x1-y, x1+y, z, color);
     drawScanlineWithDepth(y1-x, x1-y, x1+y, z, color);
     drawScanlineWithDepth(y1+y, x1-x, x1+x, z, color);
     drawScanlineWithDepth(y1-y, x1-x, x1+x, z, color);
     x++;
   }
   while(x<y);
 }
```

brings depth buffer errors, I need also calculate proper z when drawing 
scan lines. How would the 3d version of it look?

//edit

I found here, on stack, a couple of close questions, but not one
precise answer to that - there is some need for pressenham for 
spheres.. could someone answer to that?

Comment: Are you trying to draw a sphere, or are you trying to give a perspective look (further away objects are smaller) to a 2D circle? If you're trying to get a perspective look, simply scaling the `radius` proportionately to `z` might work well enough, though it won't give your normal perspective distortion.

Answer (score 1):

Just as is the case of triangles under 3d-projections, the reciprocal of 1/z behaves linearly; for every movement x+=dx or y+=dy there's involved a linear difference relation to the reciprocal of z: rec_z(x+dx,y+dy) = rec_z(x,y) + a*dx + b*dy, where a and b IIRC are almost trivially related to the normal vector of the plane.

This leads to another point: the normal vector has three components. While it's not that apparent from drawing triangles, drawing circles under perspective correction does not simply scale x and y, but there are more degrees of freedom.

([example of such image here](http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/lenapix/lenapix1208/lenapix120800095/14908051-3d-design-element-a--cube-with-cutout-sphere.jpg))  -- for copyright reasons it's a link rather than embedded.

Comment: do not bother about perspective - just need sphere rasterization alghorithm (close to that above I wrote) which wil give also z coordinate for eaxh (x,y) plotted - it would be some kind of 'double bressenham'